# ASP.NEt Tabbing Order lost when scrolling in IE

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, browser, scroll

I have a ASP.NET web page that contains many textboxes.
Each textbox has a tabindex set.

When I am tabbing through the textboxes, if i decide to click on the scroll bar to navigate the page up/down then return tabbing the tab order is reset.

The tabbing begins at the start.

I am using VS2008 and the browsers causing the problems are IE6 and IE7.

This does not seem to be a problem in Firefox.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have code changing focus in the browser? Are there timers or UpdatePanels?

Could you clarify what you mean by "tabbing begins at the start"?

Comment: No I have no code that affects the focus in the browser. No I am not using update panels. The tabbing begins at the lowest index i.e 1.

So when I am at index 4 then press the scroll bar then index is reset to 1. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fix to this. Its an IE problem.